# Unity App with Facebook login fails when deleting canvas configs

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-canvas

We're using Facebook Unity SDK for Facebook login and to query the user's friends from the app so they can play together. At the beginning we planned to create the web version of the game but we ended up creating the iOS and Android version only.

On the FB Developer console, we created the iOS, Android and Canvas version, but we needed to delete the Canvas version afterwards... and everything broke down...

Users can login with FB credentials but we can't query the user's friends anymore...

We've done apps before where no canvas is available but never with the FB Unity SDK, is this something that can't be donde with this specific SDK?

Answer (score 0):

In v2.0 of the Graph API the 'friends' edge was changed to only return 'app-friends' (friends of a user which have also logged into Facebook with that application).

If you are developing your game cross-platform and release it on Facebook Canvas you will have access to the 'invitable_friends' API which allows you to query a players full friend graph like you describe. See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends

If you are using Facebook dialogs, you can still access the full friend graph for game requests, you just cannot create your own rendering of it on mobile without using 'invitable_friends'. See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests